# Identify which Role user is assigned to

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to identify which Role a user is added to?
Because based on the user role, we need to make a measure which would display values if added in Role1 else woudl display it as blank.
The main thought behind this is we need to have a column level security wherein a column value needs to be displayed only for certain users and for all other resources it should be blank.

Note: I cannot create a user mapping table within the modle as the users list is controlled within a DL by the business

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is RLS, or row level security. You would manage this on Power BI Desktop. In the modeling tab of the app, you should see "Manage Roles" and assign further permissions from there.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.